# Nested JSON messages are not getting parsed correctly through logstash

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-7

I am trying to parse modsecurity audit logs which are natively being logged in JSON format. However when I am using logstash to ingest in elastic stack those appears like below and actual needed fields are not being parsed in their respective fields. I am not sure if any further config needed in logstash?

Here is my logstash config

```
input {
      file {
        type => "json"
        path => "/var/log/modsec_audit.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
      }
    }
filter {
        json {
          source => "message"
                skip_on_invalid_json => "true"
          tag_on_failure => ["_jsonparsefailure"]
        }
      }
```

However in Kibana those are not getting parsed correctly.
[Kibana Images for Logs Parsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zifKb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XisEL.png)

```
{
  "_index": "applox-2021.05.06",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "gldWQXkBPJxogvJE-ilc",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "host": "cwaf",
    "type": "json",
    "@version": "1",
    "path": "/var/log/modsec_audit.log",
    "transaction": {
      "host_port": 80,
      "unique_id": "16202916142.116840",
      "messages": [
        {
          "message": "Method is not allowed by policy",
          "details": {
            "reference": "v0,6",
            "maturity": "9",
            "tags": [
              "application-multi",
              "language-multi",
              "platform-multi",
              "attack-generic",
              "OWASP_CRS/POLICY/METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
              "WASCTC/WASC-15",
              "OWASP_TOP_10/A6",
              "OWASP_AppSensor/RE1",
              "PCI/12.1"
            ],
            "ruleId": "911100",
            "file": "/etc/nginx/modsec/crs/owaspcrs/rules/REQUEST-911-METHOD-ENFORCEMENT.conf",
            "rev": "2",
            "lineNumber": "27",
            "ver": "OWASP_CRS/3.0.0",
            "accuracy": "9",
            "severity": "2",
            "match": "Matched \"Operator `Within' with parameter `GET HEAD POST OPTIONS' against variable `REQUEST_METHOD' (Value: `DELETE' )",
            "data": "DELETE"
          }
        },
        {
          "message": "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 1000)",
          "details": {
            "reference": "",
            "maturity": "0",
            "tags": [
              "application-multi",
              "language-multi",
              "platform-multi",
              "attack-generic"
            ],
            "ruleId": "949110",
            "file": "/etc/nginx/modsec/crs/owaspcrs/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf",
            "rev": "",
            "lineNumber": "44",
            "ver": "",
            "accuracy": "0",
            "severity": "2",
            "match": "Matched \"Operator `Ge' with parameter `5' against variable `TX:ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `1000' )",
            "data": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "response": {
        "http_code": 403,
        "body": "<html>\r\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.20.0</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n",
        "headers": {
          "Server": "nginx/1.20.0",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Content-Length": "153",
          "Date": "Thu, 06 May 2021 09:00:14 GMT",
          "Content-Type": "text/html"
        }
      },
      "client_ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "host_ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "server_id": "30ef83bdf67cbb820de6ae6410fba661c0a34ea0",
      "request": {
        "uri": "/test.php",
        "method": "DELETE",
        "http_version": 1.1,
        "headers": {
          "Accept": "*/*",
          "Host": "localhost",
          "User-Agent": "curl/7.58.0"
        }
      },
      "producer": {
        "secrules_engine": "Enabled",
        "modsecurity": "ModSecurity v3.0.4 (Linux)",
        "components": [
          "OWASP_CRS/3.0.2\""
        ],
        "connector": "ModSecurity-nginx v1.0.1"
      },
      "client_port": 39504,
      "time_stamp": "Thu May  6 14:30:14 2021"
    },
    "message": "{\"transaction\":{\"client_ip\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"time_stamp\":\"Thu May  6 14:30:14 2021\",\"server_id\":\"30ef83bdf67cbb820de6ae6410fba661c0a34ea0\",\"client_port\":39504,\"host_ip\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"host_port\":80,\"unique_id\":\"16202916142.116840\",\"request\":{\"method\":\"DELETE\",\"http_version\":1.1,\"uri\":\"/test.php\",\"headers\":{\"Host\":\"localhost\",\"User-Agent\":\"curl/7.58.0\",\"Accept\":\"*/*\"}},\"response\":{\"body\":\"<html>\\r\\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\\r\\n<body>\\r\\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\\r\\n<hr><center>nginx/1.20.0</center>\\r\\n</body>\\r\\n</html>\\r\\n\",\"http_code\":403,\"headers\":{\"Server\":\"nginx/1.20.0\",\"Date\":\"Thu, 06 May 2021 09:00:14 GMT\",\"Content-Length\":\"153\",\"Content-Type\":\"text/html\",\"Connection\":\"keep-alive\"}},\"producer\":{\"modsecurity\":\"ModSecurity v3.0.4 (Linux)\",\"connector\":\"ModSecurity-nginx v1.0.1\",\"secrules_engine\":\"Enabled\",\"components\":[\"OWASP_CRS/3.0.2\\\"\"]},\"messages\":[{\"message\":\"Method is not allowed by policy\",\"details\":{\"match\":\"Matched \\\"Operator `Within' with parameter `GET HEAD POST OPTIONS' against variable `REQUEST_METHOD' (Value: `DELETE' )\",\"reference\":\"v0,6\",\"ruleId\":\"911100\",\"file\":\"/etc/nginx/modsec/crs/owaspcrs/rules/REQUEST-911-METHOD-ENFORCEMENT.conf\",\"lineNumber\":\"27\",\"data\":\"DELETE\",\"severity\":\"2\",\"ver\":\"OWASP_CRS/3.0.0\",\"rev\":\"2\",\"tags\":[\"application-multi\",\"language-multi\",\"platform-multi\",\"attack-generic\",\"OWASP_CRS/POLICY/METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED\",\"WASCTC/WASC-15\",\"OWASP_TOP_10/A6\",\"OWASP_AppSensor/RE1\",\"PCI/12.1\"],\"maturity\":\"9\",\"accuracy\":\"9\"}},{\"message\":\"Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 1000)\",\"details\":{\"match\":\"Matched \\\"Operator `Ge' with parameter `5' against variable `TX:ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `1000' )\",\"reference\":\"\",\"ruleId\":\"949110\",\"file\":\"/etc/nginx/modsec/crs/owaspcrs/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf\",\"lineNumber\":\"44\",\"data\":\"\",\"severity\":\"2\",\"ver\":\"\",\"rev\":\"\",\"tags\":[\"application-multi\",\"language-multi\",\"platform-multi\",\"attack-generic\"],\"maturity\":\"0\",\"accuracy\":\"0\"}}]}}",
    "@timestamp": "2021-05-06T11:01:29.155Z"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-05-06T11:01:29.155Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is expected, the `json` filter does not parse values inside an array, and it seems that the content of the field `transaction.messages` that you shared is an array where every item is a json document. You will need to use the [`split`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html) filter on this field, so every item in the array will be a new event, but you would need to update your post with an sample of your log to confirm this.

Comment: I posted a general answer to what I think you're asking... however... I wasn't able to locate unparsed JSON in the linked images

Comment: Well the messages are in a json format directly and I have updated the post for the original message

Comment: Well I tried with split - but still no luck 
``
        }
        split {
        field => "transaction.messages"
        }
      }
```
tags
_split_type_failure

Answer (score 0):

The `type` setting in the file input doesn't work this way. It's a legacy setting that basically shouldn't be used, and refers to the *elasticsearch document type* (which is now a deprecated concept) rather than the type of input file.

You might get better results using the JSON `codec`

```rb
input {
      file {
        codec => "json"
        path => "/var/log/modsec_audit.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
      }
    }
```

In this case, you'll almost certainly want to remove the json filter.

Comment: well - This is what was added while creating original file but yes coded => json was even tried and its the same result

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I resolved it with below changes in config file.

```
filter {
        split {
        field => "[transaction][messages]"
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you show full log stash config? I suppose it will work on windows given the path of audit file in json format ?